# Duplicate per-product shipping extension information - WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

on my wordpress site I have WooCommerce and the WooCommerce per product shipping extension (https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/per-product-shipping/). I currently have an issue, this is that whenever I duplicate a woocommerce product the per-product shipping information is not copied. I have tried to find a solution for this and have got the following code however I have not been able to get it work, can anyone see what is going wrong in the following

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_duplicate', 'wdm_duplicate_pps_entries',10,2);

function wdm_duplicate_pps_entries( $new_id, $post) {
   global $wpdb;
   $id = isset( $_REQUEST['post'] ) ? absint( $_REQUEST['post'] ) : '';
   if(!empty($id)) {
   $query = "Select * From " . $wpdb->prefix . "woocommerce_per_product_shipping_rule 
   Where product_id = '" . $id . "'";

   $result = $wpdb->get_results($query);
   $table_name =  $wpdb->prefix . "woocommerce_per_product_shipping_rule";

   foreach($result as $single_result) {

      $data = array('product_id' => $new_id, 'rule_country' => $single_result->rule_country, 'rule_state' => $single_result->rule_state,'rule_postcode' => $single_result->rule_postcode,'rule_cost' => $single_result->rule_cost,'rule_item_cost' => $single_result->rule_item_cost,'rule_order' => $single_result->rule_order);

     $wpdb->insert($table_name,$data);
   }

   }
}
```

This is an example of the additonal info I am trying to copy -
[image: Per Product Shipping Info]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE: Wordpress has fixed this bug

Answer (score -1):

The below code working perfect.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_duplicate_product', 'wdm_duplicate_pps_entries',10,2);

function wdm_duplicate_pps_entries( $new_id, $post) {

   global $wpdb;
   $id = isset( $_REQUEST['post'] ) ? absint( $_REQUEST['post'] ) : '';
   if(!empty($id)) {
       $query = "Select * From " . WC_PRODUCT_VENDORS_PER_PRODUCT_SHIPPING_TABLE . "
       Where product_id = '" . $id . "'";

       $result = $wpdb->get_results($query);
       $table_name =  WC_PRODUCT_VENDORS_PER_PRODUCT_SHIPPING_TABLE;

       foreach($result as $single_result) {

          $data = array('product_id' => $new_id, 'rule_country' => $single_result->rule_country, 'rule_state' => $single_result->rule_state,'rule_postcode' => $single_result->rule_postcode,'rule_cost' => $single_result->rule_cost,'rule_item_cost' => $single_result->rule_item_cost,'rule_order' => $single_result->rule_order);

         $wpdb->insert($table_name,$data);
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: How is this code different from the code posted in the question?